# How to resolve item from one site to another site in sitecore 10 SXA

Tags: sxa, multisite

I have items on one site, want to display that item in multiple sites. So how to resolve that shared items in the current site.

Template to page design mapping, header and footer should be assigned from the current site, not from the original site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to share - browsable content or datasources, nor what you have tried already (and why that did not work as expected).

For browsable content you could look at a [delegated area](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/share-content-as-a-delegated-area.html). You can do this by going to the `Configure` tab, then Clone the item(s). SXA will then ask you whether you want to make the clone an SXA delegated area. In your site, you now need to go to the `/Settings/Shared Site Settings` in your SXA site, and add your clone to the `Delegated Areas` field.

It is also possible to share presentation details or datasource items. You can do this by [designating a site as shareable](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/share-data-sources-and-presentation-using-the-multisite-feature.html). On your SXA tenant, go to the `Sharing` section and add the site you want to be able to be shared to your `Shared sites` field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an item on multiple sites in `SXA`, then you need to use the feature called, **Share content as a delegated area**.

So `SXA` provides you the functionality to share pages between sites in the same `tenant`. For that, you need to do some setup.

Read more about this using this article.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/100/sitecore-experience-accelerator/share-content-as-a-delegated-area.html

And if you want to provide the presentation of this item specific to each site then I think you can go with a `PowerShell script`, that will copy or clone your item into a new Site. So in this script, you can create a loop for Sites in your `SXA tenant` and then check if that item does not exist. Then create that for that site.

Hope this will work for you.